# Upload Laravel app from Github

Tags: laravel, github, upload, ftp, putty

I have a Laravel app in [**Github**](https://github.com/).

Say, the URL of the app is this-

> https://github.com/abrarjahin/laravel_migration_test_upwork

I came to know that there is an easiest way to upload any Laravel app from any branch of Github by some simple commands using [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) (it is so fast than uploading with [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)). And there is also way of running Laravel [Migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations) and [Seeds](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding) using [Putty](http://www.putty.org/).

But I can't find any solution how to do that.

So, can anyone please help, how can I upload server from Github and run migrations and seed ?

Thanks in advance for helping :)

Comment: So do you have an ssh access to the server? If so, install a git client on it, and just clone it into your directory. I'm using this method, you can easily update your site if anything is change. Also check *plink*, then you can place a shell script on your server, and just do a remote call to update your site.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it I need to give access to multiple users to this, then is there any way? And can u please make it as a answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: And how can I add SSH access in the server?